# MongoDB AWS Cloudformation template : Unable to connect to mongo db server from other instances

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

There is a mongo db template in AWS which is this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/welcome.html

After using that template NAT instance and Primary Node instance gets created. Now I already have a running instance, lets say it is "MyOriginalInstance", now I want to connect to mongo db from MyOriginalInstance.

The problem is that mongodb Primary Node instance does not have a public IP address so how do I even connect it?

it has local IP 10.0.2.80

I checked my inbound rules in VPC Security Group, it says allowed from all, i.e. 0.0.0.0/0 , and all necessary ports are there.

When I ssh into the primary node instance , I am able to connect to mongodb server. I can ssh the primary node only from my NAT instance, from rest of the instances I am not even able to connect to it. I did ssh ec2-user@10.0.2.80 as I had already added the ssh key to known hosts.

Then I installed mongodb on NAT instance and connected to mongo server from there but I was not able to. I did mongo 10.0.2.80 from NAT instance and connection failed.

So any idea how to connect to mongo db server using my NAT Instance and MyOriginalInstance ?

My mongod.conf

```
net:
  port:

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /log/mongod.log

storage:
  dbPath: /data
  journal:
    enabled: true

processManagement:
  fork: true
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongod/mongod.pid
```

Comment: What is the `bind_ip` setting in your mongodb server's config?

Comment: I don't have bind_ip in mongod.conf , i have added the content of it above.

Comment: Then it is bound to `127.0.0.1` by default, which will only allow localhost connections. You need to add `bind_ip = 0.0.0.0` in your config.

Comment: Still not able to connect. I did bind_ip: 0.0.0.0 as well as bindIp: 0.0.0.0, under net, nothing worked.

Comment: You restarted the server after making the change?

Comment: yes i did `sudo service mongod restart` then went to NAT instance and did `mongo 10.0.2.80` still same error.., connection failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it seems your Mongo instance is in Private subnet. So you will have to connect to the mongo instance using iptables through he NAT instance.

Check this guide from Step 4. Keep in mind the guide is for SSH into the instance you will have to modify it to ssh to Mongo Instance.

https://cloudpages.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/ssh-to-an-instance-in-private-subnet/

Comment: still unable to connect, i configured the default port 27017 from NATInstance to 27017 on mongoDBInstance using the tutorial you sent me, and then I did this from my command line in MyOriginalInstance, `mongo NATInstanceIP:27017` and `mongo NATInstanceIP` , still not able to connect, if I forward an port to 22 then I am able to connect to mongoDBInstance from MyOriginalInstance by this command `ssh -p <port> ec2-user@NATInstanceIP` but I want to connect via mongo db shell... so that I can access the mongo db